# Loading SQL X/Y Table into QGIS

Tags: qgis, sql, xy

I'm new to QGIS (moving from ESRI).
I'm wanting to use an SQL table that has X and Y coordinate columns for viewing in QGIS as a layer. I've created and tested the ODBC connection to the database ok and I'm using the code below to create a .vrt file where:
ODBC connection name is: QGISCases,
Database name: PlanningRegulations,
Table name: Cases, and
x and y fields are: X and Y

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? the error message is telling me its not a recognized data source when I try to add my .vrt as a layer.

```
<OGRVRTDataSource>
<OGRVRTLayer name="Case Manager Cases">
    <SrcDataSource>ODBC:"QGISCases","PlanningRegulations"</SrcDataSource>
<SrcLayer>"Cases"</SrcLayer>
<GeometryType>wkbPoint</GeometryType>
    <LayerSRS>"EPSG:26917"</LayerSRS>
<GeometryField encoding="PointFromColumns" x="X" y="Y"/>
</OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

QGIS version 3.22.5 64-bit
SQL Native Client 11 driver installed
SQL server 2012

Comment: Can you test your VRT from outside QGIS? eg with the GDAL/OGR command-line tools? That might tell us if its a problem with QGIS or the file or the connection or something else! (Have you tried the <SrcLayer> without quotes in the name? Possibly GDAL is passing those through to the database and its looking for a table with quotes in the actual name... I assume the table *doesn't* have quotes in the name...)

Answer (score 1):

The example for an ODBC connection for a VRT:

https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/vrt.html#example-odbc-point-layer

```
<OGRVRTDataSource>
    <OGRVRTLayer name="worms">
        <SrcDataSource>ODBC:DISEASE,worms</SrcDataSource>
        <SrcLayer>worms</SrcLayer>
        <GeometryType>wkbPoint</GeometryType>
        <LayerSRS>WGS84</LayerSRS>
        <GeometryField encoding="PointFromColumns" x="x" y="y"/>
    </OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

has a lot fewer things in quote marks than you have. I strongly suspect the quote marks in your `<SrcLayer>` tag might be breaking it, possibly the quotes in the ODBC connection string too.

Comment: Thanks for this tip. After removing the quotes I'm not getting any errors now but my SQL table isn't showing up as a layer as I had hoped. Instead I just get an empty table instead of a point layer on the map. Maybe somethng to do with my SRS definition?
<LayerSRS>EPSG:26917</LayerSRS>

Comment: Hmm no idea. I'd really want to test this with the GDAL command line tools which might get more enlightening error messages. Can you install and try running `ogrinfo` on this? Post a new question if there's a new error, since the sticking point here looks like it was the quoted name and now we're onto the next hurdle....

Comment: Hi there, sorry... I have no experience with GDAL/OGR commands (total newbie sorry). So I would require additional, specific instructions if you're up for that...

Answer (score 1):

So after a lof of searching I found a VERY simple solution to this issue.
Step 1 - add the SQL data as a table to your project
Step 2 - add a virtual layer and "import" your SQL table and create a query that makes points from the X and Y fields in the table. Now the SQL table data appears on the map using the X/Y from the table.  And if the SQL table changes, the points are automatically updated!
[image]